# CURL to C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, php, curl

I need help with converting PHP's CURL to C# HttpWebRequest. My c# code doesn't work well, the request loads all the time ending with timeout exception. Here is my PHP code:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.example.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Origin: http://media.example.com/',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Host: api.example.com',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Authorization: FD 08306ECE-C36C-4939-B65F-4225F37BD296:905664F40E29B95CF5810B2ACA85497C7430BB1498E74B52',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: */*',
        'Referer: http://example.com',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36',
        'Connection: keep-alive'
    )
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"language":"en","original_text":"' . $text . '","product":"pen"}' . chr(10));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

And here is my c# code:

```
            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.example.com/social/autocomplete/v2/search/messages") as HttpWebRequest; ;

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers["Origin"] = "http://media.example.com";
        request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";
        //request.Headers["Host"] = "api.example.com"
        request.Host = "api.example.com";
        request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "FD 08306ECE-C36C-4939-B65F-4225F37BD296:905664F40E29B95CF5810B2ACA85497C7430BB1498E74B52";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.Referer = "http://example.com/";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"language\":\"en\",\"original_text\":\"hello\",\"product\":\"pen\"}");
        string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqstr.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Basically my c# code does not return anything.

Comment: Use `HttpClient`; it's much better than `WebRequest`.

Comment: So you're asking us why your C# code isn't working, without telling us anything about the code you wrote?

Comment: I am sorry, added my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the response stream from the web server.
Use the `response.GetResponseStream()` function.

If the response contains Unicode text, you can read that text using a `StreamReader`.