# how can i do on Asp.Net?

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, header, webrequest

How can i do this on **ASP.Net (C#)** ?

```
//<?php

$host = "https://****/";

$curl = curl_init($host);


// examp is username, 1 is password for Luna Payment
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "examp:1");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 80);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

$raw_result = curl_exec($curl);

$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);


$response = json_decode($raw_result, true);

if ($response['status'] == 'OK') {

echo "Completed";

} else if ($response['status'] == 'Incomplete') {

echo "Error: No ";

} else {

$last_transaction = end($response['transactions']);

echo "Error: " . $last_transaction['error_message'];

}
```

Comment: Search for HttpWebRequest, you will find tutorials. That is the equivalence for Curl in Asp.Net

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315684/curl-to-c-sharp-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URI);

    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth ");
    req.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint:1");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Timeout = 30000;
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    //you can add remaining things like req.Headers.Add("password:XYZ");

    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if(((HttpWebResponse)(resp)).StatusCode = "OK") 
    {
     .....
    }
    else
   {
    .....
   }
```